# How can I check if CSS content property is empty using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following CSS class

```
 .ad-panel::after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 padding: 65.86% 0 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

How can I check if my .ad-panel:after class is empty? I am using the following Jquery code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

          if ($('.ad-panel').css('content','') {
            alert('No content!')
          }

    })
```

Any suggestions? I figure that the syntax is wrong somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: jQuery cannot access pseudo elements as they aren't part of the DOM, so what you're trying to do isn't possible

Comment: Would you be able to create a custom class that has your ::after stuff that would only have it, and use jquery's `.addClass()` or `.toggleClass()` to switch it on and off and then use `if($('.myDiv').hasClass('yourCustomClass')){ //do something }`

Comment: You are right. I just realized that. I just read a similar article.